# Interchange of limit and derivative of bounded convex function on half space

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let  $u\in C^2((0, \infty)^2; \mathbb{R})$ be a convex and  bounded and let
\begin{align}
  f(y)\colon= \lim_{x\to \infty}u(x, y), ~~~y >0.
\end{align}
Then, can I guarantee that $f$ is continuously twice differentiable and
\begin{align}
 f'(y) =&  \lim_{x\to \infty}u_y(x, y),\\
  f''(y) =&  \lim_{x\to \infty}u_{yy}(x, y)?
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "second derivatives are continuous"? Do you mean that the first and second derivatives exist on $(0,\infty)^2$ and can be extended continuously to $[0,\infty)^2$? Do you assume only the existence of the partial derivatives w.r.t. $y$ or of all derivatives?

Comment: Hi grew, I meant that all first and second order derivatives exist and they are continuous. I don't consider extension part. For now, only interested in behavior of infinity. I edited this post reflecting your comment

Comment: But then you have to assume that the limits exists: $u(x,y) = x$. Do you also assume that the limits of the derivatives exist or do you want to prove their existence?

Comment: I thought that the convexity and boundedness together imply the existence of limit.

Comment: Yes, of course. I missed "bounded".